# bibtex error: 1 is an integra literal, not a string

Tags: bibtex

I have a problem with bibtex. Every time I run bibtex I get the following error code:

```
Process started

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) The top-level auxiliary file: test.aux The style file: bibtex/harvardUK.bst url: is an unknown function---line 320 of file bibtex/harvardUK.bst Database file #1: bibtex/literature.bib 1 is an integer literal, not a string, for entry latex while executing---line 1485 of file bibtex/harvardUK.bst (There were 2 error messages)

Process exited with error(s)
```

I have created a small test document which I have inputted below:

```
\bibliographystyle{bibtex/harvardUK}
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn,dvipsnames,twoside,openright]{memoir} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
TEST document \cite{latex}

\bibliography{bibtex/literature}

\end{document}
```

The entry "latex" is:

```
@book{latex,
    title = {The latex companion},
    author = {Frank Mittelbach and Michel Gossens},
    year = {2004},
    number = {ISBN: 0-201-36299-6},
    publisher = {Addision-Wesley},
    series = {Handbook}
}
```

Let me know if you need more information. I hope someone is able to help me.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! As far as I can see, `harvardUK.bst` seems to be a local modification of some other bibliography style. Without having access to it, it's impossible to help.

Comment: The harvardUK.bst file is uploaded now and be seen here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/v1eawoz2dv3qy61/harvardUK.bst?dl=0

Comment: You can fix the first error by removing `URL:` in line 320; I couldn't trace the second error.

Comment: @egreg Thank you! I hope someone else is able to fix the other error.

Comment: What happens if you remove the number field from the entry?

Comment: @cfr I just tried that and I get the same error.

Comment: Did you delete generated files before recompiling?

Comment: I just double checked and yes I deleted the generated files before compliling. I only have title and author field in the entry now and gets the same error. 

I also tried with the same bst file and entry on antoher computer yesterday. I get the same error but instead of saying that the proces excited with errors it went normally and could continue afterwards.